# Como redimensionar imagens antes do upload usando c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

estou aprendendo .net mvc 4 e gostaria de saber se existe alguma biblioteca boa e simples, para redimensionar imagens antes de fazer o upload, pesquisei no google e só achei funções complexas com cálculos de redimensionamento feitos na mão. Como isso é algo bem comum, acredito que exista alguma biblioteca pronta e funcional para essa tarefa. Alguém conhece alguma?

Answer (score 1):

descobri que a biblioteca `System.Web.Helpers` possui uma classe chamada [`WebImage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webimage%28v=vs.111%29.aspx). Nela é possível fazer o redimensionamento da imagem e salvar o upload. Só precisei de uma lógica pra achar a altura correta, pois ela não permite que se passe apenas largura ou altura como parametro, então, o código ficou assim:

```
int width = 800;
int height = (int)Math.Round(((width * 1.0) / image.Width) * image.Height);
image.Resize(width, height);
image.Save(path + fileName);
```

---

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613325/resize-image-width-in-c-sharp-but-not-the-height

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que isso possa resolver:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23011/Simple-Image-Resizing-Library

e um componente que faz o redimensionamento das imagens:

http://imageresizing.net/docs/basics

Comment: a combinação dessa biblioteca com o componente é exatamente o que eu queria. Obrigado Thiago!!

Comment: Thiago, essa biblioteca funciona com a imagem em formato "FileUpload" do WebForms, preciso de uma biblioteca que funcione com "HttpPostedFileBase" do MVC. Sabe se tem como adaptar ou só com outra biblioteca mesmo?

Comment: pra você fazer funcionar com HttpPostedFileBase seria só adicionar as referências System.Web, System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase e System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper, acredito que dê certo.